# Is there a single word that means "almost certainly (but not technically 100%)"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means "almost certainly" but leaves room for 'technical' or 'philosophical' doubt. That is, something like 99.99999...% certain. Or "close enough to certain that we don't need to get hung up on it".

- **probably** doesn't work because it just means over 50% – way too low.
- **indubitably** doesn't work because it literally means "undoubtable", i.e. its definition explicitly excludes the possibility of *any* doubt.
- **definitely**, **certainly**, **doubtless** – strictly speaking, these do not allow for any doubt either (even though they are often used in casual speech for things that aren't truly certain). I want a word that, when used precisely and literally according to its dictionary definition, perhaps in a philosophical/technical/engineering context, actually *means* "certain, except for the usual 0.00000...1% doubt".

The word should *acknowledge* a shade of doubt without getting stuck on it, if that makes sense. I don't know if such a word exists, but it seems odd to me if it doesn't, as it seems like it would be very useful in epistemological and engineering discussions.

I guess "beyond reasonable doubt" is a common phrase that means roughly what I want, but I'm wondering if there is a word that (a) is a single word or simple compound, and (b) is used in more of a philosophical/technical/engineering/critical thinking context than a legal one.

Comment: Try *doubtless*.

Comment: From the description of the tag "single-word-requests": *To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*

Comment: Also, https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/probably

Comment: ***Indubitably*** there is.

Comment: Is this general usage, or the technical usage of *almost certainly* in probability theory?

Comment: So turn it around and say the probability of it *not* happening is ***infinitesimally*** small.

Comment: *Almost certainly* will almost certainly turn out to be the best term for this purpose; it is unlikely that there is a single word that will do better. Otherwise, one can just use use *certainly, indubitably* and suchlike, as long as the context renders the purely theoretical doubts irrelevant (which may be the gist of Tuffy's answer).

Comment: "Beyond reasonable doubt" doesn't mean 99.99999% (and certainly not 99.99999...% repeating, which equals 100%); it isn't precisely quantified but [some sources](https://academic.oup.com/lpr/article/5/2/167/927735) suggest high 90s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no specific potential doubt in mind then it's 'as certain as blow it'.  But that may be too casual/informal for your purpose.

If something is 99.999.... certain, then it is as 'near certain as makes no matter'.  but if the difference makes no matter, then you have no reason to doubt it at all.  And in that case, you may as well say it is certain.

The point 0.0000000...... chance of being wrong is so small that you never get to a 1 at the end.  If if such an improbability were to occur, nobody could possibly calculate its probability.  It would be like the probability of all the atoms in the chair you are sitting on moving upwards at the same instant.  We are talking about the infinite improbability drive in 'A Hitch-hiker's Guide to the Galaxy.  After all. 0.00000.... **is** infinite improbability.

Short of that, 'nearly', 'almost' or 'virtually' certain are all fine.  In real life, if the virtually impossible does happen, it will not help you to plead that in fact you were right on the grounds that it it was, in fact, virtually impossible, unless there is a precisely calculable probability.  In which case, I guarantee it will be at least 1% and probably more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning engineering, "with infinitesimal likelihood to fail", "tangentially close to target", and "asymptotically near certainty" could all be candidates for what you mean.

Note that these expressions really only fit into a scientific context, and I wouldn't expect to hear them in layman usage.

I do wonder if there's an antonym for "infinitesimal" which could be used here.

Comment: But OP also specifies a single word answer. And ELU deals with standard usages, mazunki, not technical language (especially not constructs that get zero hits in Google searches).

Answer (score 0):

> **[VIRTUALLY](https://www.lexico.com/definition/virtually)**
> ADVERB
> **1** as submodifier Nearly; almost.
>
> Source: *Lexico*

As in the statement “I am virtually certain.”

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary definition

Answer (score -1):

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/presumptively):

> *Presumptive* [*adjective*]
>
> 1. affording ground for belief or presumption: presumptive evidence.
> 2. based on likelihood or presumption: a presumptive title; the presumptive nominee.
> 3. regarded as such by presumption; based on inference; assumed: a presumptive case of pneumonia.

Comment: Nice choice for not expressing full certainty. But since "almost certainly" is an adverbial phrase, maybe "presumably" would be a better fit?

Comment: No. 'Presumptive' does not entail the '99.99999...% certain'  requirement.

Answer (score -2):

My word that suggests a virtual likelihood is the word,  **"Invariably"**.

In many dictionaries today, this word has come to mean, "always", but somehow the definition has "invariably" come to mean always.  Yet, the synonyms, suggest otherwise!  Tough call, but when using this word with the older crowd, or those who have spent a lot of time reading and composing over the past 50, 60 or more years, have acknowledged this trend, hence the word meaning 100 percent.

When using this word in a phrase, it suggests a virtual 100 percent (99.99999999999999999) probability of something happening, however there is just enough wiggle-room to suggest that it can on very very rare occasion, not be a true statement.
IT is the aformentioned that led me to make a comment regarding the OP's question!

These days, a statement will have the words, "almost invariably", once again, making the word itself and the argument for its meaning pretty strong for meaning, "always"!

Comment: No, *invariable* means what it says - 100% of the time.  Also, *virtual* means *unreal*, so when you say *virtual 100%* that means 0%, not >99%.